# In my Navigation Bar for my website, there are more clickable parts than I want. Why are they there?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a college course in the UK and I need to create a website using HTML and CSS. The navigation bar on the website looks fine but when I hover over it, there are empty bars that highlight and appear clickable when there is no text anywhere and it is really bugging me, any suggestions on how/why they have appeared?

the issue presented visually [here](https://gyazo.com/0abd4b63c4ad5e742b5a976766c0dc0e)

I have zero clues what the issue might be since I followed a video that was uploaded years ago and the channel hasn't been active in a long while so I haven't bothered commenting, hence me coming here.

This is the CSS I have for the nav bar.

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#ccc;
}

.nav ul {
    background-color:#344629;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 0px;
    font-size:17px;
    font-family:Helvetica;
}

.nav a:hover {
    background:#5e9342;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

This is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang ="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome To Lanarkshire</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</li>
        <li><a href="#">Attractions</li>
        <li><a href="#">Food & Drink</li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</html>
```

I obviously want only the text boxes to be highlighted and clickable.

Comment: You need to close the <a> tag inside the <li>

Comment: <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> - Like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing your anchor tags will likely resolve your problem. Flavio had it right in the comments...

As in:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Attractions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Food & Drink</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```